# ASP MVC5 Identity User Abstraction

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, architecture, asp.net-identity

I want to build N-tire web application with default Identity 2 provider. So, my Data layer contains pure c# classes with model definition, without any externad dependency. But it is impossible to link some classes to my Application User without adding AspNet.Identity reference.

I have tried to make an interface of User class:

```
public interface ISystemUser
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Place
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public ISystemUser User { get; set; }
}
```

And in Infrastructure layer substitute it with implementation:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, ISystemUser
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Place> Places { get; set; }
}
```

But entity framework does not creates relation between entities.

Is there any 'right' way do implement this or it is necesarry to add reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a workaround, which is pretty ugly in my opinion but works.

You will need 2 classes, one for the `User` and another for the `ApplicationUser`. `ApplicationUser` must have all properties of `User`. Like this:

```
//Domain Layer
public class User
{
     public string Id { get; set; } 
     public string Title { get; set; }
}

//Infrastructure Layer
public class ApplicationUser
{
     public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the trick is mapping the `User` class to the same table of the `ApplicationUser` class. Like this:

```
public class UserConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfig()
    {
        HasKey(u => u.Id);

        ToTable("AspNetUsers");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!