# ASP.NET Identity - How can I uncouple RoleManager (Web Layer)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

IoC (Simple Injector)

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>(() => new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>>(() => new RoleStore<IdentityRole>());
```

I have in my ApplicationOAuthProvider:

(uncouple)

```
var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

(my dependency with EF)

```
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
```

How can I uncouple my roleManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it guys (:

> No more dependencys

IoC

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>(() => new serStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string>>(() => new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
```

I created in Identity layer:

```
public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {

    }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(
    IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options,
    IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        return manager;
    }
```

and implemented

```
var roleManager = context.OwinContext.Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
```

It works!!

Tks for all

Answer (score 1):

As explained in this thread [ASP MVC5 Identity User Abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862770/asp-mvc5-identity-user-abstraction/34862983#34862983) (I am not sure if this is what your are looking for)

There is a workaround which can be used if you are developing a n-layer architecture, like DDD.

You will need 2 classes, one for the `User` and another for the `ApplicationUser`. `ApplicationUser` must have all properties of `User`. Like this:

```
//DomainLayer
public class User
{
     public string Id { get; set; } 
     public string Title { get; set; }
}

//Infrastructure Layer
public class ApplicationUser
{
     public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the trick is mapping the `User` class to the same table of the `ApplicationUser` class. Like this:

```
public class UserConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfig()
    {
        HasKey(u => u.Id);

        ToTable("AspNetUsers");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think he's talking about the table mapping, but about getting rid of the Entity Framework package dependency.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Identity uses Stores and has a set of interfaces that you can implement. The base interface is `IUserStore`, but in order to use the other functionality of ASP.NET Identity you also have to implement the other interfaces such as `IUserPasswordStore` and `IPhoneNumberStore`. [This article](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity) describes what you have to do when you want to implement your own custom stores. Here is [an example](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider) that uses a custom store with MySQL.

It's no easy task, I wrote my own stores that use Dapper and it was a lot of work, but it can be done.